# c# taking multiple lines in a texbox and separating them

Tags: c#

Hello i'm trying to write a program that takes 3 user inputs: file path, username, and computer name and then create a batch file for each computer name in the list. I have not written the create batch file part yet but I am having trouble taking the multiple computers from the computer text box and creating separate lines of code out of them.

So if there are 3 computer names inside the computer textbox, id like to when the user hits the button, output each computer name on a different line.

if the computer name textbox contained the following computer names:                                                  M22-LIBRL74258S, M22-LIBRL74257S, and M22-LIBRL74256S

the output would be :

XCOPY "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\file.exe" "\M22-LIBRL74258S\c$\Users\username\desktop"

XCOPY "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\file.exe" "\M22-LIBRL74257S\c$\Users\username\desktop"

XCOPY "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\file.exe" "\M22-LIBRL74256S\c$\Users\username\desktop"

Thanks!

```
WindowsFormsApplication1
{
       public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void browsebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {

            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a File to Send";

            // Show the Dialog.
            // If the user clicked OK in the dialog and

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string strfilename = openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory + openFileDialog1.FileName;
                pathtxt.Text = strfilename.ToString();
            }

        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void createbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string filepath = pathtxt.Text.ToString();

        string username = usertxtbox.Text.ToString();




        string computer = computerstxtbox.Text;
        string[] split = computer.Split(new char[] { '\n' });



        foreach (string l in split)
        {

            var strIP = "XCOPY \"" + pathtxt.Text + '"' + ' ' + '"' + "\\" + "\\" + l + "\\" + "c$" + "\\" + "Users" + "\\" + username + "\\" + "desktop" + '"';
            //This is to see it

            MessageBox.Show(strIP);
        }
```

Comment: The code you posted would appear to answer your own question.  Can you perhaps clarify what it is you are asking for?  Also, look into the String.Format() function. That's waaayyy too much string concatenation to be remotely readable.

Comment: Any time you are invoking `ToString()` on an instance of `string`, e.g. `strfilename`, you ought to ask yourself "What, was I thinking?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and replace the line

```
string[] split = computer.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
```

with this instead

```
string[] split = computer.Split(new String[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Also if your computer names are seperated by commas, you must also specify them in the split. e.g. new String[] {"\r\n", ","}

Comment: they would be seperated by a return with no commas. Your code output did this 

XCOPY "C:\Users\Brian\Desktop\nvidia.exe" "\\M22-LIBRL74258S
M22-LIBRL74257S
M22-LIBRL74256S\c$\Users\brian\desktop"

any other suggestions ? 

Thanks.

Comment: I have just tried the code several time and i'm getting a correct output on my end. Can you post a sample of what goes in the computerstxtbox control. Can you post it exactly as it would appear in there.

Comment: sure it is just 1 line then return 1 line return.

computer1
computer2
computer3

not horizontal like this but like in an excel file, Vertical

Comment: i get the right output for 1 of the computers but not all of them in separate lines.

Comment: so in other words they are seperated by spaces? if so then change the above code to string[] split = computer.Split(new String[] { "\r\n", " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Comment: they are separated by a Return, im not sure if that is considered a space or a not. I will try your code. Thanks

Comment: still not doing it per computer name in the computertxtbox. I think it has something to do with the for loop i need for each computer in that box to have its own line WITH the XCOPY stuff along with it.

Comment: Thats very odd, try and do a debug and check check whats in the Text property of computertxtbox. There must be something in there you are not handling correctly.